# Extract Alpha and Numerics with decimals separately containg String using java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, split, tokenize

I want to extract and split string which contains alpha and numeric characters separately.
Eg String: 2Xccc7.08DD
Output should be : [2,Xccc,7.08,DD]

I tried it using this code but it does not work.

```
myString.split("(\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)");
```

Comment: What means "it does not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `String#split(regex)` you can use this regex:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hK9oM8)

Comment: Sorry I want to Xccc as a one string

Comment: That is not what your questions says. Correct your question so that I can adjust the regex.

Comment: ok check updated regex and demo link